# How do I normalize a txt format report using regex which includes repeating headers for rows in python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to normalize this into a dataframe that will have the following fields:

- Parent_Account - these are the four digit numbers where there is no
  dollar amount in the balance/activity fields.This should repeat for
  each sub_account
- Parent_Description - description found next to parent account. This should repeat for each sub_account
- Sub_Account - these are numbers that also have a "-" and follows the first "-"
- Center - a third level in the account. Followed by the second "-". This is not always present and would be blank in that case.
- Sub_Description - the description for the Sub_Account
- Beginning_Balance - the number under the Beginning Balance. If there
  is a "cr" next to the number, it should be the number times -1
- Period_Activity- the number under the Period Activity. If there is a
  "cr" next to the number, it should be the number times -1
- Ending  - the number under the Ending. If there is a "cr" next to the
  number, it should be the number times -1

This is what my data looks like in a text file.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

string = """ gltbrp.p 2+                                         25.15.4 Trial Balance Summary                                     Date: 10/02/20
Page:    1                                                    COMP AB&E                                              Time: 16:24:55

COMP AB & E                                               Reporting Currency:   NIS
                                                           Exchange Rate:


                                                       Beginning Balance     Period Activity      Ending Balance
Account                Description                          01/01/19                                 31/12/19       Adjust Balance
----------------------- ------------------------      -------------------  -------------------  ------------------- ------ -------
 1010                   Cash-Deposit-0 Bal., FC 
 1010-1111               CFS RECEIVABLES CASH BOO            848,377.90           646,932.39         1,495,310.29  
 1010-2611               INTER ACCOUNT TRANSFERS           4,453,872.12cr        15,804,424.27        20,258,296.39  
 1010-9122               DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE          1,088,346.84         1,423,931.41cr         2,512,278.25  
 1012                   Cash-Disburse-0 Bal.,FC 
 1012-1114               QUEENSMAIN ACCOUNT              9,193,838.58         3,141,528.70cr       6,052,309.88  
 1014                   EURO CONTROL ACCT       
 1014-9122               DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE EUR          2,789.21            11,403.07cr           8,613.86cr
 1016                   USD CONTROL ACCT        
 1016-9122               DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE USD               .00            78,484.56            78,484.56  
 1022                   EURO BANK ACCOUNTS      
 1022-9122               DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE EUR      5,055,924.60         1,342,240.47cr       3,713,684.13  
 1023                   USD BANK ACCOUNTS       
 1023-9122               DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE USD      4,744,992.89         1,680,118.33cr       3,064,874.56  
 1042                   Cash-Disb.-Non.0 Bal,NFC
 1042-1162               CURR HK$ & CHINESE RMB                  330.76               330.76cr                .00  
 1100                   Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC  
 1100-1311               CFS RECEIVABLES TRADE            23,103,558.73         4,369,946.25cr      18,733,612.48  
 1100-WBAB               CFS ACCRUED RECEIVABLES             101,096.06cr           4,251.26            96,844.80cr
 1100-WBAB-1501           MAXIFIT < 300MM                    310,266.12cr          44,420.84           265,845.28cr
 1100-1315               SALES REBATES                     1,150,318.67cr          35,024.14cr       1,185,342.81cr
 1100-1315-1093           Commpac                             46,439.08cr          15,999.96cr          62,439.04cr
 1100-1315-1102           HNH IRON BALANCING                 654,359.47cr         156,251.52cr         810,610.99cr
 1100-1315-1501           MAXIFIT < 300MM                    351,099.82cr          63,893.90cr         414,993.72cr
 1100-1316               CONTACTOR REBATES                 3,804,172.43cr       2,073,515.44         1,730,656.99cr
 1100-1316-1093           Commpac                            382,263.81cr          19,739.11cr         402,002.92cr
 1100-1316-1102           HNH IRON BALANCING               1,827,536.88cr         486,674.25         1,340,862.63cr
 1100-1316-1501           MAXIFIT < 300MM                    865,491.17cr         610,548.87cr       1,476,040.04cr
 1100-1316-1502           MAXIFIT > 300MM                    321,028.94cr          73,990.76           247,038.18cr
 1100-1317               SALES REBATE CONTROL ACC          2,879,225.96cr         682,081.36         2,197,144.60cr
 1100-1317-1093           Commpac                             18,955.18cr          12,405.87             6,549.31cr
 1100-1317-1102           HNH IRON BALANCING               1,499,613.14cr         377,041.56         1,122,571.58cr
 1100-1318               Hattersley Rebates                   22,470.58cr           4,449.48cr          26,920.06cr
 1100-1318-1102           HNH IRON BALANCING                  48,921.90cr          10,152.79cr          59,074.69cr
 1100-1319               VAT TRANSFER CONTRA               2,981,496.28cr       1,243,140.41         1,738,355.87cr
 1100-1319-1501           MAXIFIT < 300MM                  1,627,262.29cr         134,977.01         1,492,285.28cr
 1100-2315               AR/AP CREDIT BAL SWITCH          11,810,820.05cr         869,957.47        10,940,862.58cr
 1100-2315-1501           MAXIFIT < 300MM                 11,810,820.05           869,957.47cr      10,940,862.58  
 1100-9122               DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE            485,594.24           254,072.72cr         231,521.52  
 1100-9122-1501           MAXIFIT < 300MM                    294,857.51             5,354.08cr         289,503.43  
 1102                   EURO ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE
 1102-9122               DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE EUR      2,433,435.33         1,022,867.13cr       1,410,568.20  
 1103                   USD ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE 
 1103-9122               DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE USD      1,801,882.57           250,490.33         2,052,372.90  
 1124                   V.A.T. Receivable       
 1124-9122               DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE          2,981,496.28         1,243,140.41cr       1,738,355.87  
 1124-9122-1501           MAXIFIT < 300MM                  1,627,262.29           134,977.01cr       1,492,285.28  
 1132                   Other Rec.-Charges Rebil
 1132-1355               CLAIMS - RECOVERABLE                  1,044.43             5,029.58cr           3,985.15cr
 1138                   Other Rec.-Employee Rec.
gltbrp.p 2+                                         25.15.4 Trial Balance Summary                                     Date: 10/02/20
Page:    2                                                    COMP AB&E                                              Time: 16:24:56

COMP BS & U                                               Reporting Currency:   NIS
                                                           Exchange Rate:


                                                       Beginning Balance     Period Activity      Ending Balance
Account                Description                          01/01/19                                 31/12/19       Adjust Balance
----------------------- ------------------------      -------------------  -------------------  ------------------- ------ -------
 1138-1321               ADVANCES TO EMPLOYEES                   100.00               100.00cr                .00  
 1138-1323               TRAVEL ADV ALL EMPLOYEES              2,357.42             1,219.98cr           1,137.44  
 1156                   Other Rec.-Pension Rec. 
 1156-9122               DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE              8,008.59             1,914.69cr           6,093.90  
 1160                   Other Rec.-Rent Rec.    
 1160-9122               DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE              3,150.00                  .00             3,150.00  
 1172                   Other Rec.-Miscellaneous
 1172-1333               COMP FUND                                 .00             6,618.31             6,618.31  
 1172-9122               DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE             26,242.01           115,117.97cr          88,875.96cr

               Beginning Date: 01/01/19
                  Ending Date: 31/12/19
       Summarize Sub-Accounts: No
       Summarize Cost Centers: No
                     Currency: NIS
        Suppress Zero Amounts: Yes
    Round to Nearest Thousand: No
  Round to Nearest Whole Unit: No
           Reporting Currency:                               Output: text
                                                           Batch ID:
"""
```

My code I am struggling with. I have just printing the output so I can see if it is correct. Group(1) seems to capture the Sub_Accounts but the other groups don't work. Really trying different things here  but no success.

```
activity_re = re.compile(r'\s(\d+-\w+(-\w+)?)\s+(.+)(\s{2,})')

for line in lines_read.split('\n'):
    line=activity_re.search(line)
    if line:
        print(line.group(1))
```

Example of desired out for Account 1010.In this case there is not "Center" number so it is blank.
[image]

Comment: Regular expression is really a great and powerful tool but you should read https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/223634/242770 and https://www.xkcd.com/1171/ :-)

Comment: BTW, your text shows a second sub-account level  at `1100-WBAB-1501` or `1100-1315-1093`. What is expected there?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta Thanks for that! I updated it. So yes, there is the parent account, a sub account, and then an optional "Center" number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re` is certainly a great tool, but is useless here because we have a fixed length fields file.

What matters is to throw away all heading lines and only process relevant ones: a *state* variable is enough to keep track whether we are processing headings or data lines.

Finaly, pandas DataFrame should be fed in one single pass, because their underlying containers are numpy arrays which indeed allow fast processing but where adding new values is expensive.

So I would build a list or better a dictionary per data line, store all those records in a list and in the end feed a DataFrame with that list of records. Code could be assuming string contains your sample data):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

header = True

def money(s):
    """Convert a number having ',' as thousand separator and a trailing cr
as negative sign to an ordinary float"""
    neg = s.endswith('cr')
    s = s.strip('cr').replace(',', '')
    return float(s) if not neg else - float(s)

data = []
colnames = ['Parent_Account', 'Parent_Description', 'Sub_Account',
        'Center', 'Sub_Description', 'Beginning_Balance',
        'Period_Activity', 'Ending']

for line in io.StringIO(string):
    if header:
        if line.strip().startswith('----------'):
            header = False
        continue
    else:
        if line.strip().startswith('gltbrp') or len(line.strip()) == 0:
            header = True
            continue
    # extract the fields from the line
    acc = line[:23].strip()
    desc = line[24:53].strip()
    begin = line[54:74].strip()
    period = line[75:95].strip()
    end = line[96:].strip()

    acc_details = len(acc.split('-', 2))
    if acc_details == 1:     # a parent record: only store parent values
        parent_row = {'Parent_Account': acc, 'Parent_Description': desc}
    else:
        row = parent_row.copy()  # initialize parent values
        if acc_details == 2:
            row['Sub_Account'] = acc[5:]
            row['Sub_Description'] = desc
            row['Center'] = ''
        else:
            row['Center'] = acc.split('-', 2)[2]
        row['Beginning_Balance'] = money(begin)
        row['Period_Activity'] = money(period)
        row['Ending'] = money(end)
        parent_row = row        # keep relevant fields for following record
        data.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = colnames)
```

which gives for `df`:

```
   Parent_Account        Parent_Description Sub_Account Center               Sub_Description  Beginning_Balance  Period_Activity       Ending
0            1010   Cash-Deposit-0 Bal., FC        1111             CFS RECEIVABLES CASH BOO          848377.90        646932.39   1495310.29
1            1010   Cash-Deposit-0 Bal., FC        2611              INTER ACCOUNT TRANSFERS        -4453872.12      15804424.27  20258296.39
2            1010   Cash-Deposit-0 Bal., FC        9122             DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE         1088346.84      -1423931.41   2512278.25
3            1012   Cash-Disburse-0 Bal.,FC        1114                   QUEENSMAIN ACCOUNT         9193838.58      -3141528.70   6052309.88
4            1014         EURO CONTROL ACCT        9122         DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE EUR            2789.21        -11403.07     -8613.86
5            1016          USD CONTROL ACCT        9122         DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE USD               0.00         78484.56     78484.56
6            1022        EURO BANK ACCOUNTS        9122         DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE EUR         5055924.60      -1342240.47   3713684.13
7            1023         USD BANK ACCOUNTS        9122         DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE USD         4744992.89      -1680118.33   3064874.56
8            1042  Cash-Disb.-Non.0 Bal,NFC        1162               CURR HK$ & CHINESE RMB             330.76          -330.76         0.00
9            1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1311                CFS RECEIVABLES TRADE        23103558.73      -4369946.25  18733612.48
10           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        WBAB              CFS ACCRUED RECEIVABLES         -101096.06          4251.26    -96844.80
11           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        WBAB   1501       CFS ACCRUED RECEIVABLES         -310266.12         44420.84   -265845.28
12           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1315                        SALES REBATES        -1150318.67        -35024.14  -1185342.81
13           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1315   1093                 SALES REBATES          -46439.08        -15999.96    -62439.04
14           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1315   1102                 SALES REBATES         -654359.47       -156251.52   -810610.99
15           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1315   1501                 SALES REBATES         -351099.82        -63893.90   -414993.72
16           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1316                    CONTACTOR REBATES        -3804172.43       2073515.44  -1730656.99
17           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1316   1093             CONTACTOR REBATES         -382263.81        -19739.11   -402002.92
18           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1316   1102             CONTACTOR REBATES        -1827536.88        486674.25  -1340862.63
19           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1316   1501             CONTACTOR REBATES         -865491.17       -610548.87  -1476040.04
20           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1316   1502             CONTACTOR REBATES         -321028.94         73990.76   -247038.18
21           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1317             SALES REBATE CONTROL ACC        -2879225.96        682081.36  -2197144.60
22           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1317   1093      SALES REBATE CONTROL ACC          -18955.18         12405.87     -6549.31
23           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1317   1102      SALES REBATE CONTROL ACC        -1499613.14        377041.56  -1122571.58
24           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1318                   Hattersley Rebates          -22470.58         -4449.48    -26920.06
25           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1318   1102            Hattersley Rebates          -48921.90        -10152.79    -59074.69
26           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1319                  VAT TRANSFER CONTRA        -2981496.28       1243140.41  -1738355.87
27           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        1319   1501           VAT TRANSFER CONTRA        -1627262.29        134977.01  -1492285.28
28           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        2315              AR/AP CREDIT BAL SWITCH       -11810820.05        869957.47 -10940862.58
29           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        2315   1501       AR/AP CREDIT BAL SWITCH        11810820.05       -869957.47  10940862.58
30           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        9122             DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE          485594.24       -254072.72    231521.52
31           1100    Accounts Rec.-Trade:FC        9122   1501      DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE          294857.51         -5354.08    289503.43
32           1102  EURO ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE        9122         DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE EUR         2433435.33      -1022867.13   1410568.20
33           1103   USD ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE        9122         DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE USD         1801882.57        250490.33   2052372.90
34           1124         V.A.T. Receivable        9122             DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE         2981496.28      -1243140.41   1738355.87
35           1124         V.A.T. Receivable        9122   1501      DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE         1627262.29       -134977.01   1492285.28
36           1132  Other Rec.-Charges Rebil        1355                 CLAIMS - RECOVERABLE            1044.43         -5029.58     -3985.15
37           1138  Other Rec.-Employee Rec.        1321                ADVANCES TO EMPLOYEES             100.00          -100.00         0.00
38           1138  Other Rec.-Employee Rec.        1323             TRAVEL ADV ALL EMPLOYEES            2357.42         -1219.98      1137.44
39           1156   Other Rec.-Pension Rec.        9122             DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE            8008.59         -1914.69      6093.90
40           1160      Other Rec.-Rent Rec.        9122             DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE            3150.00             0.00      3150.00
41           1172  Other Rec.-Miscellaneous        1333                            COMP FUND               0.00          6618.31      6618.31
42           1172  Other Rec.-Miscellaneous        9122             DEFAULT SUB-ACCOUNT CODE           26242.01       -115117.97    -88875.96
```

NB: per your requirement, the description of a Center is just omitted in my code, but it would be trivial to change it in order to add that column to the dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for the time you put in to this. What if there are no monetary values by a sub_account row? When I run it in Python it throws an error "ValueError: could not convert string to float:" which I think is because there is no value to convert. Would that require an if statement for this that sets it to 0.0 if empty?
   begin = line[54:74].strip()
    period = line[75:95].strip()
    end = line[96:].strip()

Side question, this assumes that the blank spacing is pretty much consistent?

Comment: I think this fixed it. I added or "0"
   begin = line[54:74].strip() or "0"
    period = line[75:95].strip() or "0"
    end = line[96:].strip() or "0"

Comment: I found one needle in the haystack exception. There is one parent account that has monetary values. How would I account for when this happens in the code? Thank you.
Example:
2900                   Retained Earnings                 45,415,424.56cr                .00        45,415,424.56cr

Comment: @Shmelky: I can help you to build a dataframe according to *your* requirements. But I neither know what the data actually mean, nor what you would like to do with the dataframe, so I cannot really give you advices on how you should model it.

Comment: The data is transaction data for different accounts. Unique accounts are based on the Parent-Sub_Account-Center combination (when there is a value). We have the Beginning_Balance which is the starting amount of money. We then have the Period_Activity which is how money was made or lost for each account. We then have the ending balance which is the beginning balance plus/minus what was earned/lost. This data is in a report format (the txt file) and I am trying to get it into a dataframe so that I can verify each value using external data and compare it easily by joining tables.

Comment: I tried adding the below to pull in the values when we have a parent account that has any transaction data but no luck. Not sure what is wrong.
``` if acc_details == 1:     # a parent record: only store parent values
        if (begin+period+end).replace(" ", "") != "":
            parent_row = {'Parent_Account': acc, 'Parent_Description': desc}
            row = parent_row.copy()  # initialize parent values
            row['Beginning_Balance'] = money(begin)
            row['Period_Activity'] = money(period)
            row['Ending'] = money(end) ```

Comment: @Shmelky: This is not what comments are made for, and they do not provide for code formatting. You should ask a new question and refere to that one to show your current research.

Comment: @Nev1111 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60284757/how-do-i-update-this-code-to-pull-in-a-row-that-is-not-blank-and-append-to-my-da